# Is it possible to cache just a piece(background, navigational bar) of a website instead of a whole file?

Tags: php, css, caching, web, bandwidth

I want to cache just a element because it is used on EVERY web page of mine. Here check this image out. It is explained here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/sntdz.png

Comment: in ye old days some one might suggest frames, but now no one should just reload those bits, it really should not be an issue. any images would be browser cached and the html should be of a trivial size

Comment: You probably want to look into writing more of an single page type of web application using something like React or AngularJS

Answer (score 1):

Not in the way that you are thinking. This would be server side caching. Not client side. The client caches only the elements of the page like images, videos, etc. They do not cache the actual HTML unless the entire page itself is telling them to cache it and it doesn't change from the previously cached version.

So in your example the images in all of these sections get cached, but not the HTML. The best you can do is break up the sections into their own files and cache those server side.

The biggest question is why are you caching them? If it is to save on bandwidth you won't receive any help from server side caching obviously.

You can add to your .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, public"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7257600, public"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(jpg)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, public"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(gif)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, public"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(png)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, public"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(mp4)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, public"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(flv)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

That will cache all of the elements on the page that can be cached by the client.

If you are trying to address server load issues you can cache different parts of the elements using different technologies. Memcache can cache your MySQL requests for instance and then use PHP's built in Opcode cache so the PHP isn't being compiled each time a file is run. In this case it would be best to break up the sections into their own files and have them "include"'ed into the index page.

For MySQL caching with Memcached you can wrap your code inside a request to see if the cache exists, then at the end of your code save the cached MySQL result to start the cache. That would look something like this:

```
// this little portion is standard if you have Memcache compiled into PHP.

$memcache_obj = new Memcache;
$memcache_obj->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211);

// We try to load the memcache result if it exists
$profile = $memcache_obj->get("YouPickThisNameOnYourOwn");

// Did it exist? If NOT get it from MySQL
if (!is_array($profile)) {

$mysqli = new MySQLi("localhost", "MYSQL_UserName","MYSQL_Password","MYSQL_Database");
    $sqlquery = $mysqli->query("SELECT whatever you are selecting");

// Run through and make the array you want normally...
    for ($x=0;$x < $sqlquery->num_rows;$x++) {
        $rowprofiles = $sqlquery->fetch_assoc();

    // Here I am creating an array with the results and I had selected id, text_description, subdir, crc, url from MYSQL
    $profile[$x] = array ("id" => $rowprofiles['id'], "text" => $rowprofiles['text_description'], "pic" => "http://www.domain.com/{$rowprofiles["subdir"]}/{$rowprofiles["crc"]}.jpg", "url" => $rowprofiles['url']);
    }
    // freeing up $sqlquery resource
    $sqlquery->free();

    // Here I am saving the result of the query as an associative array into memcache with a short time limite of 300 seconds. You might want longer for non changing data
    $memcache_obj->add('YouPickThisNameOnYourOwn', $profile, false, 300);

    // if I ended up using a query instead of memcache, close out the connection
    if (isset($mysqli)) { $mysqli->close(); }
}

// end if the if... had it been memcache'd the script would bypass the query and just come here with the array and spit it out
foreach ($profile as $piece) {
    echo '<div class="gallery"><img  src="'.$piece['pic'].'" alt="'.$piece['text'].'"  width="300" height="225"  border="1" /></div>';
    echo '<div class="gallery">'.substr($piece['text'],0,192).'</div>';
}

// hope this helps!
// You can run a file with just <? phpinfo(); ?> inside it to see if your host already has memcache compiled into your PHP installation.
```

Comment: Thx for understand the concept! wew. Most don't understand this!

Comment: U asked **"The biggest question is why are you caching them? If it is to save on bandwidth you won't receive any help from server side caching obviously."**  But it does save bandwidth if I could cache the elements in the red rectangular box. Data has to be transferred to the users no matter if its client-side(html/Js/CSS/Jquery) or server-side(PHP,MySql)! The picture, and text are data that is especially called every time my website is opened.It will save a lot of bandwidth b/c the elements can be called  from their local browser storage!

Comment: Could you please explain what you did on .htaccess with the <FilesMatch? Does it cache any file ending with the last file extension?

Comment: Yes, the .htaccess is to tell the clients browser that they should cache each of those particular objects for 1 year. 29030400 is seconds and equates to 336 days. So not a total year. You would only want to do this IF there won't be changes to that particular content. Like if you were going to have a header file change each month for a promotion. It would need to have its own header specified or it wouldn't update.

Comment: So does the .htaccess code cache each of the file extension you wrote?

Comment: How many ways are there to cache a website? htaccess, php file? Whats the difference? For exmaple check this out. https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/output-caching-for-beginners/ This website uses ob_start for cache but u use .htaccess. Whats the difference?

Comment: The website you referenced is caching the dynamically called contents of a website to a static html file. This is for server load. Instead of compiling and executing the PHP (and presumably MySQL) code on each load of the site this script is going to cache the output to a file that can be served instead. The .htaccess example I gave is so the server will tell the surfer's web browser to cache those files for a year. That will save you on bandwidth and possibly on server load as well since the files won't have to be served.

Comment: Thank u so much for info. U have shown the most clear path. DO u mind if I can contact u through email?

Comment: if the .htaccess code u wrote saves any of the specified file extensions into the user's browser, will the file(let's say a smiley.jpg) use the browser's cache(smiley.jpg) on every request of image named smiley.jpg independent of the different .html file?

Comment: The cached version of the file will be loaded regardless of the page that requests it. So,  on the first load of your page the browser caches the favicon file and on each load of any new pages on that domain it always reads the file from the cache. You can contact me at vrocks on gmail.

Comment: The whole idea was to not have a spam bot see the email and begin spamming me... thanks.

Comment: Sorry sorry. I deleted it!